# express receives favicon.ico as parameter for default route

Tags: node.js, express, parameters

I have this kind of route in my `/:code` and this is how I handle it :

```
router.get('/:code', (req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.params.code)
})
```

But problem is that when there is no paramter (I mean, it is empty) it logs favicon.ico . How can I prevent this? Currently I am preventing it with :

```
if(req.params.code !== 'favicon.ico'){
    console.log(req.params.code)
}
```

But I do not like it this way, so I prefer better one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is better to declare a new route for favicon 
and it should set before your existing route

```
router.get('/favicon.ico', (req,res)=>{
 return 'your faveicon'
})

router.get('/:code', (req,res)=>{
console.log(req.params.code)
})
```

I think this will fix your problem

Comment: can you pass a snippet from your code ?
also can your print what `req.url` have?

Answer (score 0):

`app.use((req, res, next) => {
    if (req.params.code == "favicon.ico") req.params.code = null;
    next();
})`

Comment: You must insert that after you listen to a port.

If that doesn't work either, please post some code.

Comment: my app is not listening to port, thats my server (http)

Comment: Please share the code, otherwise i can't help you any further.

Comment: i get that but which one listening to port, configurating app or where i /:code handler

Comment: main and router file

Comment: can you tell me what you want to see in my code because it is really large to post ere